# Xamarin Webview Gestures not firing

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to add a pinch event to my webview and did so according to the Xamarin docs:

```
        PinchGestureRecognizer pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += ClearCache;
        webview.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);
```

However, the event isn't firing. Is there something else I need to do to make it work?

Here's a messier scattergun approach with all solutions that I've come across that's also not working:

```
public class SettingsPage : ContentPage {

    ICommand tapCommand;

    public SettingsPage() {

        var url = Path.Combine(DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get(), "index.html");

        WebView webview = new WebView() {
            Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url },
            WidthRequest = 1000,
            HeightRequest = 1000
        };

        //webview.Navigating += ClearCache; ********THIS WORKS*********

        Padding = Device.OnPlatform<Thickness>(
            new Thickness(1, 20, 1, 1),
            new Thickness(1),
            new Thickness(1)
            );

        PinchGestureRecognizer pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += ClearCache;
        webview.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);


        tapCommand = new Command(OnTapped);


        TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 3 };
        tap.Tapped += ClearCache;
        tap.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "TapCommand");
        tap.Command = tapCommand;
        webview.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stackLayout.Children.Add(webview);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(btnClearCache);
        View parent = (View)webview.ParentView;
        parent.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
        parent.GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);
        Content = webview;            
    }

    private void OnTapped(object obj) {
        var service = DependencyService.Get<IPlatformService>();
        service.ClearWebViewCache();
    }

    private void ClearCache(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var service = DependencyService.Get<IPlatformService>();
        service.ClearWebViewCache();
    }

    public ICommand TapCommand {
        get { return tapCommand; }
    }
```

Comment: Does the tap gesture work, or is it all gestures not working with the WebView?

Comment: @Adam the only options are tap and pinch and neither work

Answer (score 2):

he WebView is quite nasty when it comes to gestures.

You can use MR.Gestures to handle the Down and Up gestures on iOS, Android and WinPhone 8.0 Silverlight. For Win Phone 8.1 / WinRT I didn't find a way yet.
If you only need iOS and Android, then all the gestures work on the WebView.

More info in the [compatibility table on mrgestures.com](http://www.mrgestures.com/#Compatibility).

Comment: €10 + VAT isn't bad if it solves my problem. Thanks for that. Regarding where you say WebView is nasty when it comes to gestures... could you point me to the bug tracker if it exists? I can't seem to be able to find it...